# Magento subpages give 404

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, configuration, http-status-code-404, magento

I just restored our Magento website on a different server running apache2 on ubuntu. The home page pulls up just fine but if I try to go to any other page, I get a 404.

**Permissions**

- All files are 660
- All directories are 770 All files and directories
- All files and directories belong to the www-data group

**Things I've Tried**

- check all the website and store ids
- add /index.php/ between the domain and page path
- clear temporary files

Nothing appears in the log files other than the standard 404 lines in the access.log and error.log.

**apache2 .conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin serveradmin@mydomain.com
    ServerName mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/default/"
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/default/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        php_admin_flag engine on
        php_admin_value open_basedir none
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 10G
    php_value max_execution_time 1800000
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    php_flag session.auto_start off
    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset Off

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

**Log File Output**

```
==> /var/log/apache2/oem1-error.log <==
[Tue Oct 15 12:32:21 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.4] File does not exist: /var/www/gearhead_oem1/admin

==> /var/log/apache2/oem1-access.log <==
192.168.0.4 - - [15/Oct/2013:12:32:21 -0600] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.69 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with rewrites. In Ubuntu:

Run:

```
a2enmod rewrite
apt-get install php5-curl
```

and then:

```
service apache2 restart
```

`mod_rewrite` and `php-curl` will now be enabled!

Comment: I also added php5-curl to your answer. a2enmod rewrite got me most of the way there but I was still getting some curl errors.

Answer (score 1):

Php requires different permissions. [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions#unix_file_permissions) recommends the following:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 "{}" \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 "{}" \;
```

Comment: Thank you. Giving more permission to the public doesn't change anything. If it was a permissions issue, it would have been a permissions error. Just for kicks, I changed the permissions to 775 and 664. No go.